# Does a retainer prevent underbite relapse?

Tags: dentistry, retainers

After correcting an underbite using elastic bands, I assume teeth will naturally return to their original position within the jaw unless you hold them in place, just like you would after braces/clear aligner treatment.

To keep teeth from moving back to their original position after braces/clear aligner treatment, you must wear a retainer. I can see how a retainer would keep teeth from moving relative to their immediate neighbors, but I do not understand how it would prevent the top teeth from misaligning relative to the bottom teeth and vice versa (prevent the underbite from coming back). There's nothing connecting the top teeth to the bottom teeth in a retainer to keep them in place.

I found [this article on WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/connect-to-care/teeth-straightening/can-your-overbite-come-back-after-braces). In it, a dentist is quoted as saying:

> "The retainer helps teeth stay in place until the bone remodeling and periodontal ligaments (fibers that connect teeth to the jaw bone) adapt to your new tooth position"

However, 1) they are talking about overbite, 2) it's not clear to me if the dentist is talking about the overbite, and 3) the article is poorly referenced.

Does a retainer prevent recurrence of an underbite corrected by elastic bands? If not, how is it prevented?

Comment: What has your research revealed so far? Have you verified that this is something that actually occurs or are you just assuming it does?

Comment: @CareyGregory Nothing. Everyone is talking about retainers after braces/clear aligners, but no one talks about bite correction. Someone in a forum mentioned that the dentist might overcorrect with the expectation that the teeth might bounce back somewhat, but I couldn't get confirmation that that's the case.

Comment: https://www.webmd.com/connect-to-care/teeth-straightening/can-your-overbite-come-back-after-braces

Comment: @CareyGregory And then there are articles that conflate crooked teeth with an underbite/overbite. Those two things are not the same.

Comment: My point was that your question lacks prior research. Saying it doesn't exist is untrue. Your question could have cited that WebMD article, added a brief quote from it, and asked how accurate it was. That would have made your question much better and fully compliant with site guidelines. Going beyond the layperson world and searching on google scholar or similar would have probably answered it.

Comment: @CareyGregory And my point is that the WebMD article (which I had already stumbled upon during my research days ago by the way) does not answer the question, is poorly researched, and conflates two things that are not the same. I'm not sure how it's evidence of my lack of research.

Comment: As Carey has mentioned, questions on Medical Sciences are [required to show prior research](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411). I have edited some of your comments into the question as an example of how to do that for next time.